# Linking webpages in visual studio

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have been trying to link other webpages using

```
<a href="~/Pages/a.cshtml"><li>About</li></a>
```

but when I try it it shows me the following error:

This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/Pages/a.cshtml
HTTP ERROR 404

I'm using visual studio on mac version 8.6.6
I'm using ASP.NET

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more information about what type of web site you are building. Are you using ASP.NET MVC? In that case, a URL like `"~/Pages/a.cshtml"` likely wouldn't work, as URLs are typically in the form `"~/Controller/View"`. If you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, those typically use ".aspx" pages, not ".cshtml"...

Answer (score 0):

From your anchor tag link url ~/Pages/a.cshtml it seems that you are working with MVC project.

In order to navigate (or link) pages you need something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("YourLandingPageName","YourControllerName">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the .cshtml.

If you are using ASP.NET 3.1 you can use the Anchor Tag Helper `asp-page` to go to other pages.

Below is a peice of code that works on one of my Razor Page websites:

```
<td><a asp-page="About">About</a></td>
```

So in your case just make sure to include the correct path to the page

Check out this [link](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper) for more information on Tag Helpers in ASP.NET. Pretty cool stuff.